# C++ Javascript interpreter for a text-based adventure

Tags: javascript, c++, binding, monodevelop, interpreter

I have done a bit of research and am still rather uncertain as to what exactly I am looking for. For my computer science project I had planned to create a text-based adventure engine in C++ which would read in the story files from javascript. I was hoping to find either a binding or interpreter on the web that would do some of the heavy lifting for me such as skimming through the javascript and taking out the necessary bits. I came across two projects in particular:

[http://flusspferd.github.com/](http://flusspferd.github.com)
http://code.google.com/p/tiny-js/

Flusspferd claims to be Javascript bindings for C++ and appears more reputable than TinyJS, however, TinyJS seems to be more of what I had in mind, being a "javascript interpreter", as it claims.

Overall, I would greatly appreciate some input. Perhaps I should be searching more for a string tokenizer? I find it particularly odd that there are not more popular projects out there to use javascript as a scripting language for C++. Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually want an extension language or a cheap turing tarpit? In the latter case these might be fine. But in the former case, grab one of the "big" JS engines. The thought of writing significant portions of a game in a JS implementation that doesn't even "fully implement" *objects* (and has no mention of closures) sends shivers down my spine.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know what you're saying. Is it that the way I had considered to do this is bad practice? or that I just need to incorporate a full engine rather than a mere binding?

Comment: @brianjenkins94: The point is that your research doesn't seem to be very fruitful. Searching for "javascript engine" on Google yields overwhelmingly many results about V8, Spidermonkey and Rhino, why did you pick those two, minor, unknown, inactive projects? Maybe you should have a look at [wiki's list of JS engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines).

Comment: An option to consider over Javascript is Lua. It's a nice little language with a library specifically for embedding within other programs. It already sees a fair bit of use in the game industry.

Comment: @NiklasB. I suppose what hindered my search was that I didn't particularly know what to look for. As for now, I'm looking into V8. I think that was simply the direction I needed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because everyone uses [V8 JavaScript engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) by Google?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Spider Monkey. It's Firefox's JavaScript engine. You can [read more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) or [download it](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js185-1.0.0.tar.gz).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Qt, which has a builtin ECMAScript interpreter (QtScript).

From the doc:

> Qt Script is based on the ECMAScript scripting language, as defined in
>   standard ECMA-262. Microsoft's JScript, and Netscape's JavaScript are
>   also based on the ECMAScript standard.